# Which Erlang implementation of OpenId should I use, if any?

Tags: erlang, openid, implementation

I'd need an Erlang implementation of the OpenId protocol.
I found the following, but it seems to be a project on its early stage.

http://code.google.com/p/erlopenid/

Any hint or suggestion on what should I use?

Comment: That seems to be the only one being touched in the last six months :)

Comment: They might be waiting for some issues to be registered on their projects. :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found all the existing Erlang implementations for OpenID thanks to the following search engine for Erlang projects:

http://projects.trapexit.org/web/

Here are the results:

- http://github.com/etnt/eopenid
- http://github.com/brendonh/erl_openid
- http://github.com/pib/erlangopenid
- http://code.google.com/p/erlopenid/
- http://code.google.com/p/erlopenid-mochiweb/

Comment: Which one did you use and how was your experience? Thanks!

Comment: In this duplicated thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229777/a-good-openid-implementation-in-erlang) they suggest to use http://github.com/etnt/eopenid

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, mine (http://github.com/brendonh/erl%5Fopenid) is the only one of these which supports OpenID 2.0. I can't honestly claim that it's very mature, though.