# A good OpenID implementation in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, openid, erlangweb

I'm looking for a good (Or at least working) implementation of OpenID in erlang. I've looked 
at several different solutions, but non of them are working 100%.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700786/which-erlang-implementation-of-openid-should-i-use-if-any

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have your tried eopenid? http://github.com/etnt/eopenid

You can contact Tobbe via his blog if you find some problems with it:

http://www.redhoterlang.com/entry/be023e5181553216197369bbe32c4039

Answer (score 3):

So far as I know, eopenid supports only OpenID 1.1. I have some code for doing OpenID 2.0, parts of which are based on eopenid, at http://github.com/brendonh/erl_openid (and a quick tutorial at http://taizilla.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/erl_openid/).

It's a work in progress, except that no progress is being made ;) It basically works, though, and I'd welcome help improving it.